# Technical detail in Rudin's proof of Cartan's uniqueness theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

In Rudin's "Function theory in the Unit ball of $\mathbb{C}^n$", page 23, the following theorem, due to Cartan, is stated and proven:

Suppose that $\Omega$ is a bounded connected domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$, $F:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega$ is holomorphic, $F(p)=p$ and $F'(p)=Id$ for some $p\in\Omega$. Then $F(z)=z$ for all $z\in\Omega$.

Now, the proof is very simple and clear, but there is one technical detail that baffles me. First of all, one can obviously assume $p=0$, so that there is a ball $B_1\subseteq\Omega$ of radius $r_1$ in which $F$ has a homogeneous expansion
$$F(z)=z+\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}F_s(z)$$
where every $F_s$ is a map from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$ whose components are homogeneous polynomials of degree s.
Now, we want to prove by induction on $m$ that every $F_m$ is zero. To do so, we assume the property to be true for $s<m$ and, for  $k\in\mathbb{N}$, we consider the $k$-th iterate $F^k$ of $F$.
This is where Rudin loses me: the proof continues saying that $F^k$ has homogeneous expansion
$$F^k(z)=z+kF_m(z)+\dots$$
**in B_1**.
I cannot see why $B_1$ suits for all $k$. It is true that the series of the $k$-th iterate converges on a sufficiently small ball surrounding the origin, but I do not understand how the radius could be independent from $k$. My point is that the image of $B_1$ is not necessarily contained in $B_1$, and *a priori* we know that the series expansion for $F$ is valid only on this ball.
I have found some ways to get around the problem (e.g. restricting the radius, or observing that $F$ is a biholomorphism near the origin which fixes the origin) but none of them seems to work: a fundamental part of the proof is showing that this expansion works for every $k$ in the same ball, since we want $F_m$ to be identically zero on an open set.

Is there something (possibly quite trivial) that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter that $F(B_1)$ may not be a subset of $B_1.$ If you have $F_k(z) = z+kF_m(z)+\cdots$ for $|z|$ sufficiently small, then this must hold in $B_1.$ That's because $F_k$ is holomorphic on $\Omega,$ hence on $B_1,$ hence has a homogenous expansion in $B_1.$ The coefficients for that expansion depend only the behavior of $F_k$ near $0,$ which is given by $z+kF_m(z)+\cdots.$

Comment: Well that was quite trivial indeed. Thank you kindly for your answer!

Comment: Sure thing, and welcome to MSE.